# Entity Framework : join table with different column name

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

New to Entity Framework and I need to join 4 tables, but one of the tables is not related (by name or reference) to any columns on these other 3 tables.

These are my classes/tables:

```
Locations {
   id
   platId
}

Plat {
   id
} 

Settings {
   id
   platId
   enabledCol
}

ExternalData {
   vId // Same id as Plat.id, Locations.PlatId, and Settings.PlatId
   enabled (bool)
}
```

As of right now, I have this:

```
db.Locations
  .Include(l => l.Plat)
  .ThenInclude(p => p.Setting)
  .Where(l => l.Active == true && l.Plat.Setting.enabledCol == true)
  .ToList()
```

But not sure how I can include `externalData` saying:

```
where (Plat.Id == ExternalData.vId or Locations.PlatId == vId)
```

Comment: you mean that  vId  is the Id of Plat ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your existing query set to a value, like this:

```
var result = db.Locations
    .Include(l => l.Plat)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.Setting)
    .Where(l => l.Active == true && l.Plat.Setting.enabledCol == true)
    .ToList();
```

And then you can query your `ExternalData` table separately and filter it based on the values from your `result` query:

```
var externalDataResult = db.ExternalData
    .Where(ed => 
        result.Any(r => r.Plat.Id == ed.vId) || 
        result.Any(r => r.PlatId == ed.vId))
    .ToList();
```

If you need all the data from all the tables saved in the same list, you can just keep joining each table and creating new objects from each:

```
var result = db.Locations
    .Join(db.Plat, l => l.PlatId, p => p.id, (l, p) => new { Location = l, Plat = p })
    .Join(db.Settings, lp => lp.Plat.id, s => s.platId, (lp, s) => new { LocationPlat = lp, Setting = s })
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.LocationPlat.Location.Active && x.Setting.enabledCol)
    .Join(db.ExternalData, 
          lp => new { Id = lp.LocationPlat.Plat.id, LocationPlatId = lp.LocationPlat.Location.PlatId },
          ed => new { Id = ed.vId, LocationPlatId = ed.vId },
          (lp, ed) => new { LocationPlatSetting = lp, ExternalData = ed })
    .ToList();
```